# How can I wrap/snap/fit divs into a grid layout, TETRIS style?

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time explaining in words what I am looking for, so here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/toaeb0zt/

```
<div style="width:800px ">
<div style="width:200px;height:500px; background:purple; float:left"></div>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px; background:blue; float:left"></div>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px; background:green; float:left"></div>
<div style="width:200px;height:400px; background:yellow; float:right"></div>
<div style="width:400px;height:200px; background:orange; float:left"></div>
<div style="width:200px;height:200px; background:brown; float:left"></div>
<div style="width:400px;height:200px; background:gray; float:left"></div>
<div style="width:200px;height:100px; background:red; float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

This layout was done with CSS combining left and right floats. I read about flexbox to see if it could do it, but seems like that's a negative.

I realize it could be done by nesting divs into bigger divs, but I need to make this responsive and this solution would make responsive a nightmare.

I have been trying to stay away from jQuery and deeper programming, but I understand it might be the best option. I appreciate this community's help; thank you in advance.

Comment: There are quite a few libs that will do this for you, an example would be http://masonry.desandro.com/, it requires jquery. Some other options: http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Comment: When you say, "Tetris style", are you also wanting the L-shaped piece in your layout? Or just 4-sided shapes?

Comment: @scrappedcola thank you. They seem to be able to solve my problem as long as some items can have 2 row/column width (it seems like they can).

Comment: @kevin628 only 4 sided shapes. Thank you for helping me define the issue a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you are doing seems to me like a nightmare ! there are alot of libs out there that will help you get this grid together. A masonry grid would be the most aligned with your requirement.

masonry works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.

I have used Isotope alot ! this is one of the many things you can do with Isotope:
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mEinp

```
$( function() {

  $('.isotope').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'fitColumns',
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });
});
```

study the website very carefully

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Hope this helps/ this solution  will require JavaScript (and jQuery)

Comment: thank you very much. This is a perfect example of what I am trying to accomplish. I'll look into isotope; I've heard about it numerous times; maybe it's time for me to get acquainted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table of blocks and just color each one. You can do this using css and a simple table.

Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/r3vycfa1/

I'm not positive what your looking for, but this will be more responsive.

The classes .a, .b, .c each have a different color and you can apply them to the blocks.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="a">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="a">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="b">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="b">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="b">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="c">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="c">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="c">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
}
.a {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
.b {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.c {
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time and creativity, but I wasn't clear enough. I meant to use the TETRIS analogy as to avoid whitespace between elements regardless of row or column span. Even though this does seem to solve the issue in some ways, it creates others when it comes to responsiveness and re-aligning elements. Again, thank you.

Comment: sorry, your question was not very clear, and this solution does in fact avoid whitespace between elements.